# Save Raw Pixel Data to BLOB/File

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, blob, pixel

I'm trying to make a custom web 2 print app using HTML5 canvas.
What I've learned from my research is that no matter what toDataURL for canvases cannot output hi-res files (only 72-96dpi), so what I am trying to do is obtain raw pixel data from a canvas that is 300px x 300px.

The idea is to have a 1 inch by 1 inch square because the target DPI is 300. Later I would go on to modify the canvas size in pixels for different printed materials.

I'm using `getImageData` and trying to pass that data into a Blob, which can be saved as a file.

[Here is what I have so far using JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unje7d6r/)

If you could please point out what I'm missing I'd appreciate it. The Blob being generated is invalid/corrupt for some reason.

Comment: That buffer is not in the jpeg file format, as you said it is the raw pixel data. That's why it's not working.

Comment: Ah. So how can I convert raw data to a JPEG without using toBlob or toDataURL? I thought that the raw data returned was binary, and could simply be written to a file.

Comment: You really can't, not without a lot of extremely unnecessary effort anyway. That is the specific purpose of `toBlob()` and `toDataURL()`, is to produce binary blobs and strings respectively of various image file formats. You'd have to either use a 3rd party library to generate the file format or spend a few weeks studying the binary file formats yourself and figure out how to create the file, which in my opinion are both reinventing the wheel you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/vigata/petitoJPEG was the answer. It's a perfect client-side JPG encoder. :)